# Does the Mac mini come with a keyboard or mouse?

Tags: keyboard, mac-mini, mouse

If I bought a Mac mini, would I be able to find the mouse or keyboard in the same box as what the Mac mini came in?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple provides this info on the page for buying one:  [What's in the Box.](http://www.apple.com/shop/buy-mac/mac-mini)

[image]

Answer (score 3):

No. 
The Mac Mini is famously [BYODKM](http://www.urbandictionary.com/define.php?term=BYODKM)